# What is the maximum file upload size in PHP 5?

Tags: php, file

Whta is the maximum file upload size in PHP 5? I am uploading a file of 6MB and get error 1. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's determined by [`upload_max_filesize`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize) in your php.ini.

Comment: memory_limit has to be > upload_max_filesize as well.

Answer (score 1):

check your `php.ini`:`upload_max_filesize`

That might help you :-)

Answer (score 1):

The default is 2 MB, but you can change the upload_max_filesize in the php.ini

Answer (score 0):

The above missed one setting: post_max_size in php.ini .From php doc:
"To upload large files, this value [*post_max_size*] must be larger than upload_max_filesize.

If memory limit is enabled by your configure script, *memory_limit* also affects file uploading. Generally speaking, memory_limit should be larger than post_max_size. "

Answer (score 0):

If you need to see what it is set to on your specific server, create a new file with this:

`<?php echo phpinfo();`

Then access it using your browser.